# Unusual case of unclear difference between axis = 1 and axis = 0 in pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I know the basic difference between the two and have had quite a few practical experiences with them too.
However, I was experimenting, to find out the columns having more than 0 null values in a data frame for better data cleaning and processing. I was confused by the role **axis** played here.

```
null = pd.concat([dfr.isnull().sum()],axis = 1, keys=['NA'])
```

Where "null" is the dataframe containing the count of null values in the entire dataframe and "NA" is the column these values will be represented under. This code returned a **dataframe** where I could get the columns having more than 0 null values by

`null.loc[(null['NA']>0)]`

But when I use the code :

```
null = pd.concat([dfr.isnull().sum()],axis = 0, keys=['NA'])
```

I get, what I think, is a series on which `null.loc[(null['NA']>0)]` doesn't work, apparently.
I'll attach the pictures of my output for `null.head()` for both the cases which are surprisingly very identical which confuses me.

[image: axis = 0]

[image: axis = 1]

Answer (score 1):

`dfr.isnul().sum()` returns a Series:

```
In [37]: null_sum = df.isnull().sum() 
    ...: type(null_sum)                                                                                                                                       
Out[37]: pandas.core.series.Series
```

Concatenating with both axis choices:

```
In [38]: ax0_concat = pd.concat([null_sum], axis=0, keys=['NA']) 
    ...: ax1_concat = pd.concat([null_sum], axis=1, keys=['NA'])                                                                                              

In [39]: type(ax0_concat)                                                                                                                                     
Out[39]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [40]: type(ax1_concat)                                                                                                                                     
Out[40]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

So `axis=0` returns a Series while `axis=1` returns a DataFrame. Here's why:

A single Series (`null_sum` in this case), is given as input to concat(). It will be inserted as a row or a column, depending on the value of `axis`. And  you have also used keys - according to pd.concat() documentation:

> keys : sequence, default None
> If multiple levels passed, should contain tuples. ***Construct hierarchical index using the passed keys as the outermost level.***

When the concatenation happens along columns(`axis=1`), the values of `null_sum` are added as a column, and a MultiIndex is constructed for columns with the key `NA` as the *outermost level*. But there is only one index level (since `null_sum` is a Series), so it ends up being a regular Index.

```
In [42]: type(ax1_concat.index)                                                                                                                               
Out[42]: pandas.core.indexes.base.Index
```

So we have the Index of `null_sum` as row index, and a new column index, giving us a DataFrame.

But while concatenating along rows (`axis=0`), the Series `null_sum` is added as a row, so the result is also a Series. The passed key `'NA'` is used as the *outermost level* and combined with the existing row Index to construct a MultiIndex.

```
In [41]: type(ax0_concat.index)                                                                                                                               
Out[41]: pandas.core.indexes.multi.MultiIndex
```

This is a row MultiIndex, and there is no column Index.